# First photo displaying longer than others in jquery slideshow.

Tags: jquery, gallery, slideshow

With the code as it is, one may not realize they are looking at a slideshow before navigating away. But if I increase that 3000 value to an acceptable level the rest of the slideshow is too fast. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

});
```

Comment: Probably the browser is busy with other script initializing, what might slow down the first slide being replaced. Any other `$(document).ready()` calls?

Comment: @arkascha Nothing else with $(document).ready(). The only other script is for google.